# Git merge request sequence

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

I have 3 branches   **1.master  2. feature-auth  3. feature-operations**.  `branch 2 and 3` are made from **master**.

I worked in feature-auth  and made a merge request . And its still pending.
Now I want to work in  **feature-operations**  which is created from master.  Now issue as feature-auth is still not merged  and I want some features from it in `feature-operation` . So what is best way to do to solve this lock? should I have created `feature-operation`  this branch from feature-auth ? while I read somewhere that Ideally all branches should be made from master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider rebasing `feature-operation` on top of `feature-auth`, assuming you are the only one working on that feature branch..

That way, you benefit from all commits/features from `feature-auth`, and can resume working on `feature-operation`.

```
git checkout feature-operation
git rebase feature-auth
git push --force
```

> while I read somewhere that Ideally all branches should be made from master.

That is not mandatory.

In your case, you get from:

to:

```
m--m--m--m--m  (master)
    \          / (pending MR)
     fa--fa--fa
               \
                fo'--fo'--fo' (feature-operation rebased)
```

The OP adds:

> for example I have done working on `feature-operation` and still `feature-auth` is not accepted.
> Then after completing work and before making a merge of `feature-operation` as well I have to rebase to `master`?

If `feature-operation` is based on `feature-auth` work, you will have to wait for `feature-auth` to be merged, before (indeed) rebasing `feature-operation` on top of an updated `master`.

And:

> So I should not push any changes to `feature-operation` until `master` is not updated? Or just before merge request?

While you are working on `feature-operation`, you can push that work on your remote repo as many time as you want.
Once `feature-auth` is merged to `master`, you rebase your `feature-operation` on top of `master` (after a `git pull` on `master` branch), and you `git push --force` your `feature-operation` rebased branch, and continue working (or, if you had finished, make a MR)

Comment: thanks for comment , so without merge of  feature-auth  in master I can use all feature of  feature-operations ? and its not kind of merging etc ?  Actually I can't merge code without approval

Comment: @FawadRana I have edited the answer to illustrate the effect of rebasing your second branch on top of the branch with the pending MR (Merge Request)

Comment: Why rebase at all?  If fo is a branch of fa, any changes from fa's PRs can be merged into fo either directly from fa, or from master if you want to test against up-to-date code.  If there have been substantial changes to master, we merge master into the feature branch and run tests before merging into master.

Comment: @stolenmoment rebase in order to work on fo on top of fa features (which are still being reviewed) That is what the OP needs: "Now issue as feature-auth is still not merged and I want some features from it in feature-operation"

Comment: @VonC  I run all commands , it saying  already upto date . and nothing happened

Comment: @FawadRana What happended on the `git rebase feature-auth` command (before the push)? What is your current `git status`?

Comment: @VonC   solved now got code from that branch , And kindly can you tell if it cause any issues like  Should I have to rebase master again before commenting etc ? or is there any thing I need to do to keep things stable  as  origin of  `feature-operation` is master?

Comment: @FawadRana The goal is just to get you going on working on `feature-operation`, based on current `feature-auth`, while `feature-auth` is being reviewed. Once `feature-auth` is accepted/merged, you can fetch and rebase your current working branch `feature-operation ` on top of `origin/master`

Comment: @VonC  last confusion , for example I have done working on feature-operation  and still feature-auth is not accepted . then after completing work and  before  making a merge of `feature-operation` aswell I have to rebase to master ?

Comment: @FawadRana if `feature-operation` is based on `feature-auth` work, you will have to wait for `feature-auth` to be merged, before (indeed) rebasing `feature-operation` on top of an updated `master`.

Comment: @VonC  thanks . so I should not push any changes to `feature-operation` untill master is not updated ? or just before merge request ?

Comment: @FawadRana While you are working on `feature-operation`, you can push that work on your remote repo as many time as you want. Once `feature-auth` is merged to `master`, you rebase your `feature-operation` on top of `master` (after a `git pull` on `master` branch), and you `git push --force` your `feature-operation` rebased branch, and continue working (or, if you had finished, make a MR)

Comment: @FawadRana No problem. I have included your last comment/questions in the answer itself, for more visibility: it might help others with the same questions and the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, feature branches should emerge from the same branch they will be merged to. If `feature b` depended on `feature a`, they probably should not have been different branches and different PRs to begin with.

Rebasing `feature b` onto `feature a` could mean your PR on `feature b` includes all of `feature a`, which is wrong and unfair to the approval process. Not to mention the force push, which is a bad sign.

In my view, if `feature b` needs something `feature a` has, you should just cherry pick it.

Comment: "Rebasing feature b onto feature a could mean your PR on feature b includes all of feature a, which is wrong and unfair to the approval process": This is just to get you working on b while a is approved. It is not for making a PR/MR on b itself.

Comment: What if a is not approved or is sent back for extensive changes?

Comment: As long as your goal is to work on b, it does not matter. Fix a, rebase b on top of a (again), and continue to work on b while a is getting approved (again).

Answer (score 0):

I am far from a purist, and I don't like rebase; I prefer things simple, but I also don't have a code review committee breathing down my neck, just teammates.

I would adopt @VonC's branching diagram, branch master to fa, and when fa is completed to your satisfaction, branch fa into fo.  No rebasing necessary.

If there are changes in any preceding branch that implement features you want to use, or are important for testing, merge fa or master into fo as often as you like.  If nothing else, that will simplify the final merge.

The final merge of fo into master will be closer to master than otherwise, making that final review simpler for all concerned.